# Is there any way to listen to the screen rotation events in swt based desktop applications for windows 8 Tablets?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, windows-8.1

I have a rich client application based on eclipse-plugins/rcp/swt which is being used on windows 8 touch screen tablets. As tablets have screen rotation feature with Portrait and Landscape modes, I want to change some part of the UI based on the screen mode so that UI looks better according to the current mode. Is there any way to listen to the screen rotation events in swt?

Comment: Per MSDN, [WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145210(v=vs.85).aspx) is sent to all windows when the resolution changes. I'm not sure if this could be done in pure Java though - you might need to use some native code.

Comment: Yes, native code is required for it. I was wondering if this can be done in swt itself without any native code. Thanks.